# How to Parse the JavaScript contents using DOM parser in Android?

Tags: javascript, android, parsing, dom

I am developing a news app in Android,in that I am using DOM parser to parse the various tags.I am using one php link,while opening that link in Eclipse it does not show tag

They have used JavaScript for that,so could any one help me to how to parse the javascript contents using DOM parser?

**this is my link:**
http://74.127.61.106/udayavaniIpad/headlines_unicode.php?category=882